# Icon not changing off hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an icon that changes when you hover on it. For some reason the original icon still stays. Here's my code

```
var originalContent = $('.fa-heart').html();
$('.fa-heart').hover(function() {
     $('.fa-heart').html('<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>');   
}, function() {
     $('.fa-heart').html(originalContent); 
});
```

And a demo http://jsbin.com/favukece/1/ Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Updated Code](http://jsbin.com/favukece/3/edit)**

Why not use **[`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**/**[`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)** ? The class added will override the properties of previous class.

```
$('.fa-heart').hover(function() {
     $(this).addClass('fa-heart-o');   
}, function() {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-heart-o'); 
});
```

*Update as suggested by Meagar:*

```
$('.fa-heart').hover(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');   
}, function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart'); 
});
```

In your current code, the icon is bound to the element using a `class` and not `html`.

Comment: That's not equivalent. You're adding the `fa-heart-o` class, but not removing the `fa-heart` class, resulting in both classes being active at once, where only one should be. You need `.addClass('fa-heart-o').removeClass('fa-heart')` and `'.addClass('fa-heart').removeClass('fa-heart-o')`.

Comment: Though you are right, the recently added class will override the css properties of previous class, so there is no need to remove it.

Comment: Wow, no, no it will not. That isn't how CSS works. It has nothing to do with when the class was added to the element. If that's what you think, then your answer is wrong and contains a bug.

Comment: Yes, it might happen to work in this case, which is why it's a particularly bad bug. It will not work in all cases. If the styles for `.fa-heart-o` had been listed *before* the styles for `.fa-heart` **in the stylesheet**, your example wouldn't work. Bootstrap is free to change the order of those styles at any point, so your code may break unexpectedly at any point in the future, because you've written it without understanding how CSS specificity works.

Comment: Yes, you were right. Saw some class precedence questions. +1 for your answer

Comment: @user302975, check this http://jsbin.com/catekipa/2/edit  or the demo link in my answer

Comment: Any ideas why its not changing when I try to do the icons the other way around?

Comment: It works, for other way round you need to add `.hover()` event on `.fa-hear-o`, http://jsbin.com/catekipa/2/edit. For other way round, you need `toggleClass()` as suggested my Meagar.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't what `.html` does. You're setting the *content* of the element, not replacing the element's own markup.

This is why you wind up with a nested `<i>` tag within your existing `<i>` tag.

If you want to replace the element, find its parent container and set **its** html.

Instead, since all you actually want to do is change a class, just change the class directly with `.addClass` and `.removeClass` or `.toggleClass`.

```
$('.fa-heart').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
}, function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
});
```

Comment: Can you supply a demo? It doesn't seem to be working for me http://jsbin.com/yekebeva/1/edit

Comment: @user302975 You didn't copy my code. Your code has a syntax error (missing `'`) and it's missing the second half of my `toggleClass` call. You need to toggle *both* classes. I'm not going to make a demo, just copy-paste my code as written.

Comment: *And you've written your JavaScript in the CSS field*. That Fiddle is jsbin is very broken.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is little different from the question you have asked but you might like it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
#container {
    max-width:180px;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin:20px auto 0px auto;
}


#container #menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:#FFF;
    /*border-bottom:#09F thin solid;
    border-bottom-width:3px;*/
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px 0px 50px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:13px;
}

#container #menu-wrap .menu-item {
    width: 38px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#container #menu-wrap .menu-item i {
    width:100%;
    padding:7px 0px 5px 0px;
    border-radius:3px;
}

#container #menu-wrap .menu-item i.fa-heart-o {
    background:#3B5998;
    color:#FFF;
}

#container #menu-wrap .menu-item span {
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
    color:#445878;
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:50%;
}

#container #menu-wrap .menu-item span:hover {
    top: -29px;
    font-size:20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

span.active {
    top:-20px !important;
    font-size:0px !important;
}

#container #menu-wrap .menu-item a {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#445878;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#container #menu-wrap .menu-item .text {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 17px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -27px;
    display: block;
     background-color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#container #menu-wrap .menu-item:hover > .text {
    bottom: 0;
    font-size:25px;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    text-align:center;
}

#container #menu-wrap .menu-item .icon {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    padding:13px 9px 5px 4px;
    font-size:25px;
    text-align:center;
}

html, body{
     margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
   }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="menu-wrap">
      <div class="menu-item">
            <span id="active" class="fa fa-heart-o"></span>
            <a id="hover" class="text" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```